# current ST t No undefined in React Native AsyncStorage function

Tags: react-native

I have a data array and when I set a value from the array into AsyncStorage it shows as undefined.

Data Array

```
Ticket Data Object {
  "contactNo": "0",
  "createdAt": "2021-08-06 13:27:55",
  "id": 1,
}
```

Function

```
fetch(`${API_URL}/v1/serviceTicket`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'apiKey': 'asdkhjfgsed34e',
                'deviceId': deviceId,
                'sessionId': sessionId

            },
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => {
                // console.log('service ticket data', json, ' base API : ', API_URL)
                if (!json.success ) {
                    if (json.errorCode === 403) {
                        sessionExpire()
                    }
                } else if(json.data){
                    setserviceTData(json.data)
                    console.log('Ticket Data',json.data)
                    
                    if(json.data.tasks){ttData(json.data.tasks)}
                    setSTNo();
                }
               
            }
            )
```

This shows up in my console `current ST t No undefined`
Any suggestions..

Comment: what is `serviceTData`?. Does it have the property `id` ?

Comment: Also you should use `JSON.stringify()` to stringify your object.